# Android: Settings "onResume"?

Tags: android, settings

I'm working on a Android App and the layout and all the "android" specific stuff made a friend of my. I only was responsible for the "app" itself.

Nevertheless,
I would like to change some settings, e.g. change the server the stats produced by the app, should be transfered.
Here is the Settings.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Settings extends Activity {

private Context mContext;
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefEditor;

private EditText textName, textIP;

private RadioButton rdOnline, rdOffline;
private RadioGroup rdGroup;

private Button butSpeichern;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mContext = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    mPrefEditor = mPrefs.edit();

    textName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBenutzer);
    textIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtIP);

    rdOffline = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdOffline);
    rdOnline = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdOnline);
    rdGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioDB);


    butSpeichern = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeichern);

    butSpeichern.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveSettings();
        }
    });

    //Online default an
    rdOnline.setChecked(true);
    rdOffline.setChecked(false);
    loadSettings();
    //ggf. Lan
    System.out.println("online");
    if(automatischLAN()){
        setLan();
    }

}
private void saveSettings()
{
    mPrefEditor.putBoolean("onlineDB", rdOnline.isChecked());
    mPrefEditor.putString("benutzer", textName.getText().toString());
    mPrefEditor.putString("ip", textIP.getText().toString());

    mPrefEditor.apply();
    finish();
}

private void loadSettings() {
    textName.setText(mPrefs.getString("benutzer", ""));
    textIP.setText(mPrefs.getString("ip", "192.168.0.50"));
    rdOnline.setChecked(mPrefs.getBoolean("onlineDB", true));
    rdOffline.setChecked(!mPrefs.getBoolean("onlineDB", true));
}

public boolean automatischLAN(){
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    Date currenttimen = new Date();
            cal.setTime(currenttimen);
     int freitag = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int STUNDE = 0;
    STUNDE = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    System.out.println(STUNDE);
    if(freitag == Calendar.FRIDAY && STUNDE>11 && STUNDE< 14 )  {
        System.out.println("lan");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("online");
        return true;
    }
}

public void onBackPressed()
{
    saveSettings();
    super.onBackPressed();
}

public void setLan(){
    rdOnline.setChecked(false);
    rdOffline.setChecked(true);
    System.out.println("sollte lan sein");
    mPrefEditor.putBoolean("onlineDB", rdOnline.isChecked());
 }

 }
```

I'm afraid my `setLan()` method isn't working as the values are not stored in the prefs...

What is the easieast way to check prefs and chance them on each start of the app?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to commit the changes in the SharedPreference.Editor variable. Replace your function above with the given one

```
public void setLan(){
    rdOnline.setChecked(false);
    rdOffline.setChecked(true);
    System.out.println("sollte lan sein");
    mPrefEditor.putBoolean("onlineDB", rdOnline.isChecked());
    mPrefEditor.apply();
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks...that solved this problem ;)
however, is there a chance to show up the settings activity an each start of the app?
right now it only appears after the installation

Comment: You should accept the answer to make easier for users going through same problem in the future.

Comment: Just call the settings activity after loading the activity.